# After using LookupOperation , The larger the number of pages, the longer the query time takes

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregate, lookup

I'm using SpringBoot 2.7.12, and mongoDB version 3.4
When I query like this, whatever page I want to query, for instance, size is 500 then
the speed are same for every value of skip

```
class Repository {
    public List<EntityResponse> findListOfEntities(int skip, int size) {
        SkipOperation skipOperation = Aggregation.skip(skip);
        LimitOperation limitOperation = Aggregation.limit(size); 
        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
                skipOperation,
                limitOperation
        ),"entity", EntityResponse.class).getMappedResults();
    }
```

}

But if I use LookupOperation. And after that I make query again

```
public List<EntityResponse> findListOfEntities(int skip, int size) {

        LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().from("favours")
                .localField("game_id")
                .foreignField("game_id")
                .as("games");
        SkipOperation skipOperation = Aggregation.skip(skip);
        LimitOperation limitOperation = Aggregation.limit(size);

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
                lookupOperation,
                skipOperation,
                limitOperation),"entity",EntityResponse.class).getMappedResults();
    }
```

The speed of query will depend's on how big is skip. The larger of skip, the longer query takes.
For instance :
with size of 500, when skip is zero it ~10ms only,
but for skip = 10, its ~ 100ms,
and skip = 100, its ~ 700ms.
anyone has any idea for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following base claim is incorrect:

> When I query like this, whatever page I want to query, for instance, size is 500 then the speed are same for every value of skip

It may be true that the impact is *smaller* and less noticeable, but there's nothing about your description of the environment that suggests the database is able to process larger `skip` values as efficiently as smaller ones. I suspect that if you were to do closer inspection (e.g. profile the query or gather the execution stats via `explain`) that you would see that the command is processing a total number of documents equal to the values provided for `skip` and `limit` .

Moreover, `$lookup` in MongoDB is going to do work for each document passed to it from the preceding stage(s) in the pipeline. It would therefore make sense that the amount of work, and therefore execution time, increases linearly with the amount of data being passed to it from the earlier stages.

Here are some suggestions:

- Since the `$skip` and `$limit` do not impact and are not impacted by the `$lookup`, move those stages before the `$lookup` in the pipeline. Based on your description, this change alone will probably resolve your issue.
- Make sure there is an index on or leading with the `game_id` field in the `favours` collection.
- Upgrade the database. New versions of the database may automatically reorder your pipeline as suggested above without you having to do so manually by the client.
- If this data is processed sequentially, convert the code to use a single cursor with appropriately sized batches or implement keyset pagination.

One additional note - skipping and limiting without also sorting/ordering the results is typically a bug. The database is not required to process the request in the same order and therefore may miss or return duplicate results across subsequent requests.